# How many MB of data are downloaded while installing Ubuntu 12.10 via internet connection?

Tags: system-installation, updates, internet, files

I am in a hostel that offers 300-1000MB codes of free internet. I know that I can just install via a Boot CD or USB without an internet connection, but I'm wondering if I will be able to install directly from the internet with my currently limited resources.

I am not asking how large the installer and I am not asking if I can install Ubuntu without the internet.

Can anyone tell me how much data is downloaded while installing from the internet?

Will updates be a significant portion of the downloaded data?  Could I do those updates once I am in a new location next week?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think they are about 200-300 MB language packs and the same amount for updates. I suggest you install without Internet; you always have enough time to install updates or language packs. After you installed, Software Updater will tell you how much download is needed.

Comment: Also, you'll never know how much it will download. Because the updates will be more heavy while more time has passed since your release has been released. @AliNa Could you (please) create an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As my experience, there are **about 200 MB for language packs** (will be different for different languages) and **200-300 MB for updates** if you have checked the box in the step *preparing to install*.

Since it may takes long time to download and install new packages, I recommend you to install Ubuntu without any Internet connections. It will be installed in about 10 minutes only. After you installed it succesfully, you can run **Software Updater** to see the available updates and their sizes, then if you have a limited Internet traffic, you can choose between them to be installed. And if your language is English, you can ignore language packs as well.